# Calculating probability of pressing button three times and hearing sound at the third press

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider the situation:

There are two mysterious buttons in front of you. One of the buttons is harmless, whenever you press it, nothing happens. The other button is mostly harmless, when you press it,nothing happens with probability 2/3 but with probability 1/3, pressing the button results in a loud siren! Unfortunately you don't know which button is which.

I have to answer the following:

Suppose you pick a button at random and press it twice. Suppose nothing happens either
time you press it. What's the probability when you press it a third time that you hear the siren?

I am stuck trying to calculate this. As of right now all I have calculated is the event that you pick a button and press it twice and do not hear a siren (call this event S).

So P(S) = (1/2) + (1/2)((2/3)^2) = 13/18

(I used the law of total probability to calculate the above value)

Now I want to calculate the event that I hear a siren on the third try after not hearing it the two tries before. How would I go about doing so? I can't seem to wrap my head around this problem.

Comment: it's like throwing dices. First the probability to pick the correct button is $\frac{1}{2}$ now that this button will not beep at the first has probability $\frac{1}{2}$, for the second time two and that it beeps the third time again, so you got $\frac{1}{16}$

Comment: Well this is not taking into consideration that one of the button only beeps with the probability 1/3, and another button wont make a siren at all. It is more complicated than you are suggesting. @mjb4

Comment: I would use a long stick to push the buttons. People capable of setting this up are capable of arranging that either button drop heavy weights on your head.

Comment: @WillJagy Really does not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T$ be the event that you hear a siren on the third try (but not the first two tries). Then:
\begin{align*}
\text{Pr}(T \mid S) &= \frac{\text{Pr}(S \cap T)}{\text{Pr}(S)} \\
&= \frac{\text{Pr}(T)}{\text{Pr}(S)} \\
&= \frac{\frac{1}{2} \cdot (\frac{2}{3})^2(\frac{1}{3})}{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (\frac{2}{3})^2} \\
&= \frac{4}{39}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let's say button $A$ is harmless, but button $B$ has a $1/3$ chance of yelling at you. If you press $A$ twice, there's a $1/1$ chance nothing happens. If you press $B$ twice, there's a $4/9$ chance that nothing happens.

Now if you press a random button twice and nothing happens, then the probability of you having chose $A$ is
$$\frac{1}{1+(4/9)}=9/13$$

Probability of having chose $B$ is
$$\frac{4/9}{1+(4/9)}=4/13$$

EXPLANATION:

[image]

Here are the probabilities for $A$ and $B$ for not hearing a siren after $2$ presses. Don't really know which button you chose, but you know you are in this blue area. The probability that you are in $A$'s blue area is:

$$\frac{1}{1+(4/9)}=9/13$$

Now if you chose $A$, the probability of hearing a siren on the $3$rd try is $0$. If you chose $B$, then the probability of hearing the siren is $1/3$.

The probability of hearing the siren on the $3$rd press after choosing a random button and not hearing the siren on the first two presses, is

$$\frac9{13}\cdot0+\frac4{13}\cdot\frac13=\frac4{39}$$

Comment: Thank you, the only thing I don't understand is why you do       1/(1+(4/9)) and not 1 + 4/9? why is 4/9 going in the denominator? @user137794

Comment: I added an explanation for that part